# Get values of all items in DynamoDB table and display (Android)

Tags: android, amazon-dynamodb, database-scan

I am having problem with DynamoDB. I dont have any idea on how to get all items in table (in this case, DynamoDBTable) of DynamoDB and display it. I tried to use Scan but it gives me error of null exception.

ScanTable

```js
public void ScanTable() throws Exception {

        DynamoDBMapper mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(client);

        System.out.println("Scanning Tesis");

        DynamoDBScanExpression scanExpression = new DynamoDBScanExpression();

        List<DynamoDBTable> result = mapper.scan(DynamoDBTable.class, scanExpression);
        System.out.println(result.toString());

        for (DynamoDBTest tesis : result) {
           System.out.println(tesis.toString());
        }
```

DynamoDBTable

```js
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "Tesis")
public class DynamoDBTest {

        private String Title;
        private String id;
        private String Author;
        private String Year;
        private String Supervisor;
        private String Program;

        @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "Id")
        @DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey
        public String getId ()
        {
            return id;
        }
        public void setId (String id)
        {
            this.id = id;
        }

        @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "Title")
        public String getTitle()
        {
            return Title;
        }
        public void setTitle (String Title)
        {
            this.Title = Title;
        }

        @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "Author")
        public String getAuthor ()
        {
            return Author;
        }
        public void setAuthor (String Author)
        {
            this.Author = Author;
        }

        @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "Year")
        public String getYear ()
        {
            return Year;
        }
        public void setYear (String Year)
        {
            this.Year = Year;
        }

        @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "Supervisor")
        public String getSupervisor ()
        {
            return Supervisor;
        }
        public void setSupervisor (String Supervisor)
        {
            this.Supervisor = Supervisor;
        }

        @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "Program")
        public String getProgram ()
        {
            return Program;
        }
        public void setProgram (String Program)
        {
            this.Program = Program;
        }
}
```

```js
6-28 21:35:47.816  10939-10939/com.example.user.test2 I/System.out﹕ Scanning Tesis
06-28 21:35:47.826  10939-10939/com.example.user.test2 W/System.err﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException
06-28 21:35:47.826  10939-10939/com.example.user.test2 W/System.err﹕ at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBMapper.scan(DynamoDBMapper.java:2007)
06-28 21:35:47.826  10939-10939/com.example.user.test2 W/System.err﹕ at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBMapper.scan(DynamoDBMapper.java:1971)
06-28 21:35:47.826  10939-10939/com.example.user.test2 W/System.err﹕ at com.example.user.test2.DynamoGetItem.ScanTable(DynamoGetItem.java:53)
06-28 21:35:47.826  10939-10939/com.example.user.test2 W/System.err﹕ at com.example.user.test2.DynamoGetItem.onCreate(DynamoGetItem.java:30)
06-28 21:35:47.826  10939-10939/com.example.user.test2 W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5411)
06-28 21:35:47.826  10939-10939/com.example.user.test2 W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
06-28 21:35:47.826  10939-10939/com.example.user.test2 W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
06-28 21:35:47.826  10939-10939/com.example.user.test2 W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2396)
06-28 21:35:47.826  10939-10939/com.example.user.test2 W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
06-28 21:35:47.826  10939-10939/com.example.user.test2 W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1293)
06-28 21:35:47.826  10939-10939/com.example.user.test2 W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-28 21:35:47.826  10939-10939/com.example.user.test2 W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
06-28 21:35:47.826  10939-10939/com.example.user.test2 W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
06-28 21:35:47.826  10939-10939/com.example.user.test2 W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-28 21:35:47.826  10939-10939/com.example.user.test2 W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-28 21:35:47.826  10939-10939/com.example.user.test2 W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-28 21:35:47.826  10939-10939/com.example.user.test2 W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
06-28 21:35:47.826  10939-10939/com.example.user.test2 W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

[image]

Is there anything I did wrong?

Comment: can you share the exception stack + the table definition you did in the DynamoDB console?

Comment: Hi yes i have editted my post. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AmazonDynamoDB db is declared on [this line](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-android/blob/master/aws-android-sdk-ddb-mapper/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/mobileconnectors/dynamodbv2/dynamodbmapper/DynamoDBMapper.java) of the most recent version of Android SDK. Your NPE is happening on the [call to the scan](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-android/blob/master/aws-android-sdk-ddb-mapper/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/mobileconnectors/dynamodbv2/dynamodbmapper/DynamoDBMapper.java#L2007) method of db field. It appears that the AmazonDynamoDB field may be null and is not set. Did you [create a DynamoDB client and inject it in the Mapper](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/developerguide/dynamodb_om.html#create-a-dynamodb-client-and-object-mapper)? In other words, is the client variable above set? Finally, it seems like the initial snippet of your call instantiation `List<DynamoDBTable> result = mapper.scan(DynamoDBTable.class, scanExpression);` should use `DynamoDBTest.class` instead of `DynamoDBTable.class`.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<DynamoDBTable> result = mapper.scan(DynamoDBTable.class, scanExpression);
    System.out.println(result.toString());

    for (DynamoDBTest tesis : result) {
       System.out.println(tesis.getTitle.toString());
    }
```

you will get all the titles